# Angular 6, Injector, Singleton

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, reference

How can I inject a service in angular by it's injector, to keep service singleton?

---

here my code part

```
const injector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: UserService, deps: []}]});
const service = injector.get(UserService);
```

---

Need to keep singleton features of the service. For example I have `EditorComponet` and have `UserComponent` and keep reference of object which is injected in constructor, so need exactly same thing for manual injection, see code which I provided.

Comment: Are you trying to use the injector as a factory?

Comment: Angular services are already singletons